# Разделить datatime на дату и время

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

В [датафреме](https://dropmefiles.com/ITEuQ) неправильно отображается дата и время - оно сливается. Как можно разделить datatime на Date и Time?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: использовать strftime() https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#strftime-and-strptime-behavior

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вот, к примеру, как можно это сделать:

```
import pandas

df = pd.read_csv("12.csv", parse_dates=["datetime"])

df["Date"] = df["datetime"].dt.date
df["Time"] = df["datetime"].dt.time
```

теперь df:

```
              datetime  Count        Date      Time
0  2021-09-24 00:15:00   3887  2021-09-24  00:15:00
1  2021-09-24 00:20:00   7355  2021-09-24  00:20:00
2  2021-09-24 00:25:00   7587  2021-09-24  00:25:00
3  2021-09-24 00:30:00   5619  2021-09-24  00:30:00
4  2021-09-24 00:35:00   5500  2021-09-24  00:35:00
..                 ...    ...         ...       ...
94 2021-09-25 01:20:00    900  2021-09-25  01:20:00
95 2021-09-25 01:25:00   1600  2021-09-25  01:25:00
96 2021-09-25 01:30:00   2598  2021-09-25  01:30:00
97 2021-09-25 01:35:00   1400  2021-09-25  01:35:00
98 2021-09-25 01:40:00   2196  2021-09-25  01:40:00
```